# Using rsyslog in zookeeper

Tags: logs, rsyslog

I have installed `ZooKeeper`. `ZooKeeper` by default uses Apache's `log4j`. I need the `ZooKeeper` logs to go to `rsyslog`. But I do not know how to do this.  How do I configure `ZooKeeper` to use `rsyslog`?

Answer (score 2):

You need to configure `log4j` of `zookeeper` respectively. This can be done in `/etc/zookeeper/conf/log4j.properties`. Note that you are then interfering with the installed defaults. I don't know yet how to configure this in such a way that it survives an upgrade properly.

Change the rootLogger

```
log4j.rootLogger=info,syslog
```

and add

```
#syslog
log4j.appender.syslog=org.apache.log4j.net.SyslogAppender
log4j.appender.syslog.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.syslog.syslogHost=localhost
log4j.appender.syslog.facility=user
```

The SyslogAppender uses default port 514, [which cannot be changed](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/log4j/log4j/1.2.17/org/apache/log4j/helpers/SyslogWriter.java/), and UDP, which cannot be changed either. So make sure in your `rsyslog.conf` that you have uncommented the lines

```
$ModLoad imudp
$UDPServerRun 514
```

Check [SyslogAppender](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/log4j/net/SyslogAppender.html) to find out more parameters to set, like facility.